# Get LimeSurvey not selected multiple choice answers with "N" using API Remote Control

Tags: api, limesurvey

Is it possible to get not selected answers in multiple choice question type marked with "N" when consuming Lime Survey API?

The API method `export_responses` gives all the question/subquestions/answers codes of user responses in bulk.

But the multiple choice question type signalizes only the selected answers with an "Y". I'd like responses bring the answers not selected with an "N" written. LimeSurvey can do that?

Example:
listTpFisioAt is the question code; *text*, in listTpFisioAt[*text*], is an option. When I consume the API to get responses I get something like this:

```
lisTpFisioAt[Fototerapia]
lisTpFisioAt[Termoterapia]
lisTpFisioAt[Cinesioterapia]   Y
lisTpFisioAt[Eletroterapia]
lisTpFisioAt[Hidroterapia]   Y
```

In this case user selected *Cinesioterapia* and *Hidroterapia* in Lime Survey interface.

I'd like to get:

```
lisTpFisioAt[Fototerapia]   N
lisTpFisioAt[Termoterapia]   N
lisTpFisioAt[Cinesioterapia]   Y
lisTpFisioAt[Eletroterapia]   N
lisTpFisioAt[Hidroterapia]   Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, is not possible. Limesurvey fills checked options only. The other ones are left empty. You will need to fill the empty ones yourself by processing the output.

Hope it helps.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I suspected that. Thanks to confirming me @Gabriel.